# sql : not able to find the view (WITH statement)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables. Inbound_table, Outbound_table and Transfer_Table. I want to perform a full outer join for all three tables in Mysql. Using the following query:

```
WITH
InOut_Table as 
(select *

from Inbound_Table left join Outbound_Table
on Inbound_Table.A = Outbound_Table.A

and Inbound_Table.B = Outbound_Table.B

and Inbound_Table.C = Outbound_Table.C

and Inbound_Table.D = Outbound_Table.D
UNION
select *

from Inbound_Table RIGHT join Outbound_Table
on Inbound_Table.A = Outbound_Table.A

and Inbound_Table.B = Outbound_Table.B

and Inbound_Table.C = Outbound_Table.C

and Inbound_Table.D = Outbound_Table.D
),
final_table as
(select *

from InOut_Table left join Transfer_Table
on InOut_Table.A = Transfer_Table.A

and InOut_Table.B = Transfer_Table.B

and InOut_Table.C = Transfer_Table.C

and InOut_Table.D = Transfer_Table.D
UNION
select *

from InOut_Table RIGHT join Transfer_Table
on InOut_Table.A = Transfer_Table.A

and InOut_Table.B = Transfer_Table.B

and InOut_Table.C = Transfer_Table.C

and InOut_Table.D = Transfer_Table.D
)
select *
from final_table
```

Firstly, I am getting an error saying "InOut_Table.D" is invalid. It is not able to get any of the columns for InOut_Table. Similar error for A,B and C too. Cannot understand why. Is it changing the column names?
Secondly, I am sure I have not written the query in the best way possible. Can you please suggest how to write it in the optimized way.

Comment: MySQL does not support common table expressions (that is, the `with` clause).  I'm surprised you are not getting an error on the first `with`.

Answer (score 1):

My Sql does not support WITH clause, you can use temporary tables,inline views in mysql.

In your case, temporary tables would be simpler.